# Dividing an area into redundant parts

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, area

Is it possible to divide a square into $n>2$ parts, such that any $m$ of these $n$ parts can be used to reconstruct the original square, wherein $1<m<n$? The parts may overlap, but cannot rotate.

For the simple case of $n=3$ and $m=2$, I found a solution: dividing the square into four quadrants and then defining the three pieces to be:

1. top left, bottom left, bottom right quadrants,
2. top left, top right, bottom left quadrants,
3. top left, top right, bottom right quadrants.

Is it possible to answer this question for arbitrary $n$, $m$?

Comment: Given $n$, let $A_1,A_2,\dotsc,A_n$ be any $n$ disjoint subsets of the square, and then define the $n$ pieces to be what you get by removing one of the $A_i$ from the square (that is, for the 1st piece, remove just $A_1$, for the 2nd piece, remove just $A_2$, etc. Then for any $m>1$, any subset of $m$ pieces can be used to reconstruct the square.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK wow, that's a really elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $n$, let $A_1,A_2,\dotsc,A_n$ be any $n$ disjoint subsets of the square, and then define the $n$ pieces to be what you get by removing one of the $A_i$ from the square (that is, for the 1st piece, remove just $A_1$, for the 2nd piece, remove just $A_2$, etc. Then for any $m>1$, any subset of $m$ pieces can be used to reconstruct the square.